# My pros-cons question was closed - what's the difference between it and the on-topic pros-cons questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I noticed that there are quite a few questions which start with 'What are the pros and cons of using -this feature-...' I promptly posted a [question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/301/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-an-indexed-for-loop-to-iterate-over-a-vector) about using different types of for loops. Apparently it isn't on-topic for this site, so it got the close hammer.

I would really like to know what the difference was between my question and, say, [this question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-do-while-loops). From my point of view, the questions both ask about 'best practice'. Is there anything I'm missing here that is making the question not a good fit for this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seemed specific to C++ vectors, and [a more general version of it already exists](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/193/what-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-c-style-for-loops). I can’t speak to anything more specific, though, as I’m not one of the close voters.